# In Visual Source Safe is there a limit to how many labels you can apply?

Tags: visual-sourcesafe, visual-sourcesafe-2005

We have a collection of 25 or so projects in a source safe database and we want to apply daily labels to each of them.  Is there a limit to the number of labels that can be applied?

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: That is typical for daily builds. New build applies a new label.

Comment: @sharptooth: yep, for some reason I thought the poster was talking about CI builds...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've been using one repository for 5 years so far. It stores numerous projects and something like ten daily builds run every day on that repository. Every daily build creates a new label on some project every time it runs. So far we haven't seen any problems with possible labels exhaustion.

Comment: we considered this in our nightly build machine, but ultimately rejected labeling each nightly build - what are the benefits of this decision?  Wouldn't it simply clutter the tree?

Comment: @Nate: With labeling each build you can repeat every build at any moment in the future. For example, you release your software and nine months later you need to produce a patch - a new version of one of the numerous binaries - to address one specific problem. That will be much faster than release the software again. So you just grab all the sources using that label and apply only the necessary changes to them.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no *practical* limit. We once did what you ask about - daily builds applied a label with the build number, this went on for several years.